# where subquery in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery, laravel-5.8

I have 3 tables in mysql.

this table name : admin_activities_logs. Here Instant_id is the Users table pk and instant_type is table name.

```
id   instant_id  instant_type   action 

1     1           users          create
2     2           services       update
3     2           users          delete
4     1           services       create
```

users table:

```
id    name    email
1     test    test@gmail.com
2     user1   user@gmail.com
```

this services table:

```
id   titile
1    test service
2    service 1
```

this is my table and i want to get result :

```
id    instant_id  instant_type action    user_name    services
1      1           users        create    test          -
2      2           services     update      -           service1
3      2           users        delete     user1         -
4      1           services     create       -          test service
```

how to get this user using laravel eloquent.help me

and i try this

```
DB::table('admin_activities_logs as aal')
    ->where(function($query){
        return $query->leftjoin('users as u', function ($join) {
           return $join->on('aal.instant_id', '=', 'u.id')
                 ->where('aal.instant_type', 'users');
        });
    })->select('*')
    
    ->get();
```

Comment: @TimLewis i try this